# Google Map generated from typescript / javascript showing as grey box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript

I've got the following typescript class that produces a google map instance. I'm new to javascript / typescript and HTML!

```
/// <reference path="./google.maps.d.ts" />
module Mapping {
    export class GoogleMap implements IMap {

        public name: string;
        private map: any;
        private options: any;

        constructor (mapDiv: Element) {
            this.name = "GoogleMap";
            this.options = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.83305, -1.66412), zoom: 3, MapTypeId: 'terrian' };
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, this.options);
        }
    }
}
```

and in my view, I have the following ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>TypeScript Mapping</title></head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKEYGOESHERE&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/typings/Mapping.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                Mapping.GoogleMap(mapCanvas);
            }
        </script>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map" style="height: 512px; width: 512px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

All I get at runtime is a grey box, dragging inside this box changes the pointer to the hand pointer so it looks like the control has been created ok just not showing any maps details.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hate the grey box. I'm not certain of what the solution is, since it could be any number of problems, so I'll comment instead of answering -- is your container's size determined post page load? If so, when instantiated, Google Maps will assume its container is 0x0, and render a map of that size. You'll have to trigger the google maps "resize" event by calling `google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, 'resize');`

Comment: thanks for that Julian, unfortunately it doesn't seem to sort my problem.

Comment: Should've actually written out `google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');` instead of `mapObj`, but I presume you tried that as well. If I think of anything else, I'll re-comment.

Comment: Hello again, looking at the values you passed to instantiate the map, it looks like passing 'terrain' isn't correct. Try passing `google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN` instead (an object, rather than a string)

Comment: Hi Julian, I just spotted that and it fixes it ;Changed to              this.options =  {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.83305, -1.66412),
                    zoom: 3,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to echo the finding from the comments:

It looks like your map options are defined incorrectly. Try...

```
constructor (mapDiv: Element) {
    this.name = "GoogleMap";
    this.options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.83305, -1.66412),
        zoom: 3,
        MapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, this.options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

Google's `MapTypeId` is an constant so you can directly go for the property here like:

```
google.maps.MapTypeId.CONSTANT
```

Currently they support 4 Types:

```
Constant    - Description
HYBRID      - Displays a photographic map + roads and city names
ROADMAP     - Displays a normal, default 2D map
SATELLITE   - Displays a photographic map
TERRAIN     - Displays a map with mountains, rivers, etc.
```

---

**Addon:**

I've created a short Demo Application in TypeScript for a Google Maps in an TypeScript Application/Page:

https://github.com/DominikAngerer/typescript-google-maps

It currently support:

- Default Google Maps
- SnazzyMap Support (simply replace your SnazzyMap with the one I configured in the SnazzyMaps.ts)
- Default Center Object
- Free Geo IP Location (10.000 Request per Hour)
- New Default Icon /images/icon.png
- New Default Icon as .PSD /images/icon.psd
- No jQuery Needed
- Generated Test Data from Json-Generator.com
- InfoBox JS Plugin
- Infobox Example
- Template example for InfoBoxes
- Full bower support

On the todo is also typings support, so issue's as you got there shouldn't happen again.